# Creating a method that will sum nested values for blackjack

Tags: python, string, list, methods, int

I am working on a Python Blackjack game and I have it set up to take the user name and to create a deck that will randomly shuffle and display a hand to the user.

I would also like to display a running total for the user. Given the user may "hit", I would like to make this a method I can recall for a cleaner code.

I started work on it (see code below), however I am stuck as to how to write a proper method to do this. I would assume some str to int conversion must happen and "face cards" must be assigned values of 10. Also an Ace would ideally run through some sort of conditional loop where if the total is under 11 it counts as an 11 but if the total is over 11 it counts as 1.

```
user_name = input("Please enter your name:")
print ("Welcome to the table {}. Let's deal!".format(user_name))

import random

suits = ["Heart", "Diamond", "Spade", "Club"]    
ranks = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
deck = [(suit, rank) for rank in ranks for suit in suits]

random.shuffle(deck,random.random)

user_hand = []
dealer_hand = []
user_hand.append(deck.pop())
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())
user_hand.append(deck.pop())
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())

def handtotal (hand):
    total = 0
    rank = [][1]

    for rank in hand:
        if rank == "J" or "Q" or "K":
            total += 10
        elif rank ==


print ("Your current hand is {}".format(user_hand))

user_hitstay = input("Will you hit (H) or stay (S)":)
```

Comment: What is your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
try:
    total += int(card)
with ValueError:
    # must be a face card...
    if val == 'K':
        total += 13
    elif val == 'Q':
        ...
    elif val == 'A' and total <= 10:
        ...
    elif val == 'A' and total > 10:
        ...
```

where card is one of the strings

Answer (score 0):

```
for rank in hand:
    if rank == "J" or "Q" or "K":
        total += 10
    elif rank == 'A' and total < 11:
        total += 11
    elif rank == 'A' and total >= 11:
        total += 1
```

...... and so on

you can just add the rest of the conditions